# Intelligently handling puppet master unavailable (almost caching)

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Is there a good way to set up caching for Puppet, specifically templates? I have a number of modules that would be really, really useful to have available in a DR situation.

**Proposed Solution**

I know there isn't an inbuilt way to set up caching directly, based on the [template documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html). Natively templates are rendered server side and there isn't a direct way to change this.

I was thinking about using a custom mount point  to pull down specific modules I flag for offline use. 
This would be pointed back to the same directory puppet master reads from, to avoid things getting out of sync. I actually already have the basics for this working.

Once I have a local copy some kind of logic could perform a puppet run using the local mirror.

This would be a pseudo masterless puppet, something like

```
puppet apply --modulepath ./modules manifests/site.pp
```

How can I have effectively have puppet say *puppet master isn't available, so execute these commands*?

Comment: I presume there are reasons you don't want a masterless puppet setup?

Comment: Do you need the templates to be re-rendered based on dynamic fact values? I ask because the agent **does** cache templated files out of the box.

Comment: @FelixFrank that is exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the master is operating normally, the agent will update the timestamp on `$vardir/state/state.yaml` on every run. A failing master (including compiler errors etc.) will lead to an outdated `state.yaml` file. You can use its freshness to determine whether your master is up and well.